# -[object Object]- error on Google Distance Matrix - Android and iOS

Tags: javascript, android, ios, google-maps, distance-matrix

Suddenly, without any code changes, my apps stop working. It’s taxi system with driver/passenger apps.

Now, when passenger choose start point and destination point - instead of calculation of route I get:

**Unknown error -[object Object]-**

Billing enabled within Developer console, Distance Matrix enabled, API key enabled, nothing changed - but apps (both OS) throws error.

Any help or suggestion appreciated. I know this is javascript array/string related, but **nothing withing code changed**

**Edit**

Additional logcat error:

```
com.google.android.gms.persistent W/GLSUser: [DeviceKeyStore] Cannot load key: Device key file not found.
```

Comment: This looks like a Firebase issue, not Distance Matrix.

Comment: Maybe this thread can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50168155/ioexception-while-requesting-key-invalid-device-key-response